# Why java in Linux on each thread creates descriptors to jar dependency files?

Tags: java, linux, jvm, jvm-hotspot

The problem of a large number of file descriptors in the system. Checked with lsof. And I noticed that for each java stream file descriptors are created for each jar file in the dependency folder. Total number of descriptors = number of threads * number of dependency files. With a large number of files in dependencies, its creates a problem "Too many open files".

Why is it so arranged in JVM? And is it possible to require descriptors of jar files to be reused between threads?

(There is a variant - "fat jar", but it is not convenient for deployment)

OS Debian GNU/Linux 8. JVM HotSpot 1.8.0_66

Comment: Could you please provide your lsof output? What does java stream and dependency folder mean? Could you please provide one line reproducer https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve?

Comment: Iv seen issues where getResourceAsStream calls were returning InputStreams and were not being closed (a good old fashioned resource leak), and causing run away file handles.

Comment: +slipperyseal Sadly enough, this happens also when not using getResourceAsStream at all (see sample code in post)